# Toggle disabled button dependant on select field

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Issue:**

I have a modal window with input fields that trigger a disabled save button once filled in. I now want to integrate a select box into this modal instead of the normal text inputs and can't figure out how to get the script to recognize them seeing as it's not a true text input, it's a select. I have an example here of the working code prior to addition of the select box: [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/kID8La1Zdn)

**Question:**

What do I need to place in my script to be able to use the select fields instead of input fields? I think it may have something to do with telling it to look for a variable coming from a text input rather than an option coming from a select. This is an example of what I want to work: [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/LwxLs801sn)

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: You can use the `.change()` event handler for a select box just like you do for a text input.

Comment: As Barmar said; your code is not that big, and you can strip down the HTML portion to only the relevant part (such as the form, or even just the inputs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You cannot listen to the `keyup` event as `<select></select>` elements do not use this in the same way as `<input></input>` elements. In order to listen for a change in the selected option you need to use the `.change()` event.
2. You cannot use the `placeholder=""` attribute on a `<select></select>` as the element will select by default the first `<option></option>` child. Change this to having the first option as `<option val="">Please Select</option>` or similar.
3. You have to check the selected `option` of a `<select></select>` in order to see if the value is blank. To do this you have to use `$('#select').find('option:selected').val() == "")`.

Full Code:

`HTML:`

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="projectName" value="Johnny Appleseed" style="display: inline; width: 325px;">
        </div>
        <div class="cloudcontainer">
          <!-- NEW FIELD ADDED HERE -->
        </div>
        <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">Add New Field</a>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- MODAL -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">New Field</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form">
          <div class="field">
            <label>State:</label>
            <select id="fieldtitle">
              <option value="">Enter State</option>
              <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
              <option value="AL">Alaska</option>
              <option value="AL">Arkansas</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label>City:</label>
            <select id="fieldtitle">
              <option value="">Enter City</option>
              <option value="BR">Burmingham</option>
              <option value="JN">Juneau</option>
              <option value="LR">Little Rock</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="clickme" disabled="disabled" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`JS:`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".field select").change(function(){
        var empty = false;
        $(".field select").each(function(){
            if ($(this).find('option:selected').val() == "") {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if(empty) {
            $("#clickme").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $("#clickme").attr('disabled', false);
        }

    });

});
```

Link to bootply: http://www.bootply.com/1cpZMLBuwv

Answer (score 2):

Instead of listening to the `keyup` event you need to use the `change` event to know when the value of the select fields has change.

`$(".field select").change(function(){ ...`